# Fix position:fixed in iOS 4

Tags: ios, ios4, cordova

I am building a small app using PhoneGap HTML/CSS. Now my problem is that `position:fixed` (used on a top bar) works on iOS 5 but not on iOS 4. Someone knows a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Position:fixed doesn't work on iOS before version 5 and some other mobile browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html). There are a lot of solutions out there for this, but one that I can personally recommend is [GloveBox](https://github.com/purplecabbage/GloveBox) written by Nitobi's own Jesse MacFadyen. It lets you define areas that are scrollable, and I believe in your case that would be the main content, while the top bar isn't scrollable.
Another advantage of this approach is that the user won't be able to "scroll out" of your app's view as if it were a normal website on Mobile Safari.