# navbar phonegap plugin

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, cordova, uinavigationbar, native

I would like to add a navigation bar at the top of "some" of my phonegap based ios application pages. I have tried using JQM based headers and they don't seem to be steady enough ( i.e. they scroll when I scroll the content and jump back).  I would like to use a native control using a phonegap plugin ( like NativeControls) However I haven't been able to find anything ( as far as I can tell NativeControls used to have navbar control but it got discontinued) Any ideas? suggestions?

One of the options is to use a tool bar control on the top of the page but then it does not really have a way to create a title in the middle and buttons on left and right. Also it has no way of adding the native "back" control either.

I have been researching it for a while but haven't been able to find anything.

Update:

I ended up writing my own Navbar and hooking it to a javascript call through phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this edited plugin for UINavigationbar 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/XVru2zgB_yc

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. Didn't find any plugins for this also.

This is what I did:

- I've created a CSS NavBar/TopBar with position:fixed
- Used this solution to make it work on iOS 4 too: [Fix position:fixed in iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701515/fix-positionfixed-in-ios-4)