# jquery mobile fixed navBar position on iOS 4

Tags: jquery, css, xcode, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app using jquery mobile and last issue to be solved is compatibility between iOS4 and iOS5. Navigation bar can be fixed easily on iOS5 using position:fixed. However, on iOS4 does not work! I have been trying different methods but none of them quite reliable enough. How to get navigation bar fixed on iOS4 like iOS5 does?? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix position:fixed in iOS 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701515/fix-positionfixed-in-ios-4) ?

Comment: not duplicate, this is not a reliable solution, doesn't work :(

Comment: have you tried also http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/fix_your_position_even_in_ios_4 ?

Comment: thanks but same issue, has an ugly element reposition, far from native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrollView plugin does the trick. No others worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
```